# Meteor using Template.registerHelpers,

Tags: meteor, registerhelper

I am trying to combine 2 beginner classes together (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates & http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/iron-router-part-1/). I have been able to complete both classes individually with no problem.

I am using `Iron:Router` to route to various templates. I run in to issues  when I try to access a template within a template. The proper results do not get displayed on the  " aostasks"page.

**.js**:

```
Router.route('aostask', {

    template: 'aostask'
});

 Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.registerHelpers('task', function () {
      return tasks.find({});
    })
  };
```

**.html**:

```
<template name= "aostask">

    <head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>



</template>
<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

**Result:**

A page with the correct headers.However, it does not list the tasks i have in my mongo collection. Is the issue that i am using the registerHelper function incorrectly? Should i be using some other function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo in your helper name

```
Template.registerHelper('tasks', function () {
      return tasks.find({});
    })
  };
```

`tasks` not `task`

Comment: Thanks! correction  collection was named 'Tasks' with a capital T. I have since updated my naming convention.                                  Tasksdb = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.registerHelper('tasks', function () {
      return Tasksdb.find({});
    })
  };

Answer (score 0):

Your helper is registered with the same name as your template. It should be just 'task'. Template.registerHelpers should be Template.registerHelper

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.registerHelper('task', function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    })
  };
```